# How to import a wallet created with Tezbox via command line

Tags: wallets, tezbox, tezos-signer, password

Does anybody know how to import the Tezox address via command line? I created it with a secret phrase and a password.  I don't see any way to import that to Galleon or via command line with a node set up.  It's the Seed Words/Mnemonics phrase.

Comment: So you want to import an address created with Tezbox, into Tezbox?

Comment: You also mention Galleon and the Tezos node. Do you want to import into Galleon, or into `tezos-client` (which is also a simple wallet)?

Comment: Are you running the tezbox desktop wallet? The tezbox website refers to 5 versions (android, windows, os x, chrome).

Comment: Either way, it should contain a "export private key". You can then import this key into the `tezos-client` basic wallet using the `tezos-client import secret key <alias> <key>` command.

Answer (score 0):

with tezbox, you can go to wallet options and view the private key, then you can import that private key via command line:

./tezos-client import secret key  unencrypted:

note: edesk means the secret is encrypted with a password you created, edsk means unencrypted an anyone with the secret key can take your Tezos